# How to build a search engine box in web-development

Tags: javascript, css, search-engine, visual-web-developer

I would like to make a search engine box where I can search country names.
About the User Interface, I want it to be like Google search engine box.
It activates when a user tries to type something, and it does not close by clicking the input typing box.
It only closes when the user clicks outside the input box or a recommendation keyword.
How can I build this type of search engine box? 
If it is possible, can you please show me some of the codes as well? Thank you a lot.

[Google search engine box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqjZA.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Welp, you'll need an `<input type="text />` for the search bar. Style it up and give it functionality in js.
I suggest making an array of countries or getting from the internet and for every interaction with the search bar, give our some results with jquery.